Plotting points on a line and assigning coordinates?
I have a picture of a line that I want to trace and plot points across evenly like this.
I've been searching forever but haven't found out how I can:

plot points across a picture of a line
assign coordinates to the points
then I can pick any two points and calculate the slope between them using their coordinates

enter image description: picture of line
enter image description: line with points plotted along it
I'm a new coder and I've been watching videos on pyautogui and OpenCV but haven't been able to find specific tutorials on how to best accomplish this. Any advice would be so much appreciated.

Calculating a slope is simple math, take the difference between the Y coordinates and divide by the difference between the X coordinates.
